# How to identify file vs folder from DriveId

Tags: google-drive-android-api

When working with Google Drive Android API (GDAA), I often need to retrieve  a list of parents of a GDAA object identified by DriveId. But I could not find a direct method that would deliver the list of parents. The only way to get it is to turn the DriveId into DriveFile or DriveFolder, and subsequently apply listParents(GoogleApiClient) method.

And here, I run into a situation where the code for getting parents turns ugly, something like (*it is simplified, original has try/catch logic as well*):

```
static private GoogleApiClient mGAC;
...  
ArrayList<DriveId> getParents(DriveId dId) {
    ArrayList<DriveId> prnts = new ArrayList<>();
    if (dId != null) {
      DriveFile dFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGAC, dId);
      if (dFile != null) {
        MetadataBufferResult rslt =  dFile.listParents(mGAC).await();
        if (rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
          MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
          try {
            mdb = rslt.getMetadataBuffer();
            for (Metadata md : mdb) {
              if (md == null || !md.isDataValid() || md.isTrashed()) continue;
              prnts.add(md.getDriveId();
            }
          } finally { if (mdb != null) mdb.close(); }
        }
      } else {
        DriveFolder dFldr = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGAC, dId);
        if (dFldr != null) {
          MetadataBufferResult rslt =  dFldr.listParents(mGAC).await();
          if (rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
            try {
              mdb = rslt.getMetadataBuffer();
              for (Metadata md : mdb) {
                if (md == null || !md.isDataValid() || md.isTrashed()) continue;
                prnts.add(md.getDriveId();
              }
            } finally { if (mdb != null) mdb.close(); }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return prnts;
  }
```

resume:

- checking if DriveId turns successfully into DriveFile, and if not, re-test it with DriveFolder is really kludgy.
- I don't understand why can't I get parent Id directly from DriveId. What difference does it possibly make if the DriveId represents file or folder.

So it boils down to 2 questions:

1. Is there some method/indicator that allows me to identify DriveId as file or folder?
2. Is there some method I don't know about that would allow me to get list of parents without going through the getFile() / getFolder() gauntlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am happy to report that with evolution of the GDAA, a method

> DriveId.getResourceType()

has been introduced, allowing to retrieve the type of the Drive object directly. Here is an example of code the does that:

```
/**
 * FOLDER type object inquiry
 * @param driveId Drive ID
 * @return TRUE if FOLDER, FALSE otherwise
 */
static boolean isFolder(DriveId driveId) {
  return driveId != null && driveId.getResourceType() == DriveId.RESOURCE_TYPE_FOLDER;
}

/**
 * FILE type object inquiry
 * @param driveId Drive ID
 * @return TRUE if FILE, FALSE otherwise
 */
static boolean isFile(DriveId driveId) {
  return driveId != null && driveId.getResourceType() == DriveId.RESOURCE_TYPE_FILE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following method: Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query);

You will have to create the appropiate query to access the parents of a file. The good thing about this solution is that it relies on the DriveId instead of a FileId or FolderId. The solution should be something similar to:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.PARENTS, "DriveId"))
    .build();
Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query);
```

You can read more about this solution in the following page: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries

Comment: Your answer translates to: "find object(s) whose parent DriveId is 'DriveId:AbC...' ". I was asking how o resolve question "find all parents of an object whose DriveId is 'DriveId:XyZ...' ". See, Google Drive objects (files/folders) can have multiple parents.

Comment: According to the DriveAPI documentation, you'll get the result that you are asking about. In the Drive Web API, such method exists: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list

Comment: By using the Query method from Android API, you should get a similar response.

Comment: I would let it go, but since SO is a source of info for many developers, I just can't accept answer that is wrong. You are right about the RESTful DriveAPI, it has parents/list, but your answer for Google Drive Android API (GDAA) will list CHILDREN not PARENTS of "DriveId". And btw, it is 'Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENT,...' not Filters.eq(...). You can test it with a piece of code I put on GIST https://gist.github.com/seanpjanson/da8b915bc54ee7288b07, since it does not format here.

Comment: About the RESTful DriveAPI. Your suggestion is overkill, since 'list' method can already deliver an array of parents objects. See 'https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list' and use playground at the bottom with fields: items(parents/id,title). Or in your code, use something like:
List qry = mGooSvc.files().list().setQ("'me' in owners").setFields("items(parents/id, title), nextPageToken") and you can enumerate parents for every single list item.